utils:::readCitationFile slowing down a Shiny App
So I made an a Shiny app and have one of its panel taking a lot of time to render, and I'm looking for a way to optimize it. To checkout which part of my code takes the most time, I used profvis to profile my app but I don't know where to go from here.
Here is the profile of what seems to be the main issue :

As you can see, the most time consuming element seems to be utils:::readCitationFile taking half of the 15 seconds to create this panel alone. However nowhere in my code do I call this function, or at least not explicitly (as some package functions might call it by default).
Unfortunately I can't share a reproducible example of the issue as it is designed around confidential data, but has anyone encountered this issue and might know how to remedy it ?

EDIT :
After cleaning the code and reducing it to make it a reproducible exemple, I optimized bits of the legacy code I'm working with that seemed to be the cause of the slowdowns, meaning that my issue is actually resolved.
I am still not sure what exactly is the cause and how profvis imputed it on utils:::readCitationFile, but I will try to explain what I did in case someone find a similar issue.
First of all, req(). Some key reactives in the App didn't called req() before being evaluated and adding it to them already sped up the app significantly and reduced the time "supposedly" taken by  utils:::readCitationFile, so be sure to systematically use it.
Secondly, I used RcppRoll cumsum() and roll_sum() functions on a data frame containing the data of various categories on 3 years with all 12 months (around 250 lines) when I only needed this data on 2 years. This change seems to have made the biggest performance improvment, but since I also did various other modifications and fixes, I can't say for sure that RcppRoll is to blame.
I will leave this question open for answers for now in case I find precisely what caused the issue that I could provide with a reproducible exemple.

Maybe you are able to share a reproducible example using dummy data? It's very difficult to help with you with the given information. I'd start finding out which function is calling utils:::readCitationFile in the first place.

The March 2024 release of shiny (v1.8.1) introduced ExtendedTask, which seems made for just this sort of situation.  Wrap the reading of the citation file in an ExtendedTask and it won't block the loading of the rest of the UI.

As your dataset is confidential, you can synthesise the issue by, for example, putting a call to sleep in a similar peice of code that reads a small, non-confidential citation file.  Help yourself by helping us to help you.  Do you call citation() anywhere in your code?

I'm working on converting my App into a reproducible exemple. Along the confidential data there's also the fact that it is a multi-file app with lots of dependencies and a "messy" readibility (that I am cleaning since I took over the legacy code, but it takes time). I estimate the current "minimal" exemple to be +800 lines long, I will edit the question with it when it will be at most 300 lines long
